# How to create array with 100 numbers without using loop in php?

Tags: php

How to create array with 100 numbers without using loop in php?
I want to create array, something like that:

```
array ([0]=>'1%', [1]=>'2%',...)
```

I'm using now:

```
array_combine(range(0,100),range(0,100));
```

2. Question: How to make range with step 0.5 ?

Comment: I found only that sollution, but I don't know how to add to values sign of '%'     
    array_combine(range(0,100),range(0,100));

Comment: Please add your attempts in your question, by [editing your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28676348/edit)

Comment: why be afraid of loops? You're filling an array. Even if you don't explicitly write out a `for` loop, internally the system is STILL going to be using some kind of loop...

Answer (score 4):

This should work for you:

(Here I used [`range()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) with [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to create an array from `1%` to `100%`)

```
$arr = array_map(function($v){return sprintf("%d%%", $v);}, range(1, 100));
print_r($arr);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1%
    [1] => 2%
    [2] => 3%
    //...
    [99] => 100%
)
```

**EDIT:**

How you can define a step for `range()` is pretty good documented in the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php

And a quote from there:

> array range ( mixed $start , mixed $end **[, number $step = 1 ]** )

Comment: Thank you, how to make range in your example with step .5 not 1?

Comment: I tried that and it doesn't work for me: 

`array_map(function($v){return sprintf("%d%%", $v);}, range(1, 200,.5));`

Comment: @Jerzy Ah if you want to use it with this just use this: `array_map(function($v){return sprintf("%.1f%%", $v);}, range(1, 200,.5));`